# Proof that $\int_0^\infty \mathcal{X}_{\{x:|f(x)| \geq t\}} dt = |f(x)|$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I was doing a exercise in Bass Measure Theory book in the chapter about Fubini Theorem. The question is quite straightforward to prove the following:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| dx = \int_{0}^\infty m(\{x:|f(x)| \geq t\}) dt$$

Where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. The main idea is to use Fubini and change the order of integration. Doing this I arrive at the following:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \int_{0}^\infty \mathcal{X}_{\{x:|f(x)| \geq t\}} dt \right)dm$$

but then I arrive at the integral in question and I have no intuition why it must be equal to $|f(x)|$ as we are actually integrating with respect to $t$. Any intuition or ideas?

Comment: so, $t$ is going from $0$ to max $|f(x)|$ so the integral should look like $$\int _0^{|f(x)|}1dt.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $x$ the integrand can be looked at as a function having $t$ as argument:

$$\mathcal{X}_{\{x:|f(x)| \geq t\}}=1\iff t\leq |f(x)|\iff \mathcal{X}_{(-\infty,|f(x)|]}(t)=1$$

So that:$$\int_0^{\infty} \mathcal{X}_{\{x:|f(x)| \geq t\}}dt=\int_0^{\infty}\mathcal{X}_{(-\infty,|f(x)|]}(t)dt=\int_0^{|f(x)|}dt=|f(x)|$$